# How to api-query for the default vhost

Tags: rabbitmq

The RabbitMQ [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) states:

```
Default Virtual Host and User

When the server first starts running, and detects that its database is uninitialised or has been deleted, it initialises a fresh database with the following resources:

a virtual host named /
```

The [api](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html) has things like:

```
/api/exchanges/#vhost#/?name?/bindings
```

where "?name?" is a specific exchange-name.

However, what does one put in for the **#vhost#** for the ***default***-vhost?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As write here: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html

> As the default virtual host is called "/", this will need to be encoded as "%2f".

so:

```
/api/exchanges/%2f/{exchange_name}/bindings/source
```

full:

```
http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/test_ex/bindings/source
```

as result:

```
[{"source":"test_ex","vhost":"/","destination":"test_queue","destination_type":"queue","routing_key":"","arguments":{},"properties_key":"~"}]
```

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!  It was there the whole time.  Thx.

Comment: This is a real awkward design decision for a great product. As a consumer, you will only end up here and learn the simple true answer by starting to think like "hmm, default vhost is a slash char and I must use it in a http url, so there must be some kind of escape or encoding? let's google that". Thanks a lot for the simple truth though.

Comment: This is not a RABBITMQ decision, but if from AMQP protocol. @BeytanKurt :)